# Check if time interval falls into the today

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a Core Data with events and a calendar, what I need is to build a predicate request to get only the event that fall in today. For example:

EVENTS (in Core Data table it is two Attributes with type Date)

```
1) Start 10/01/2015 14:00:00 Ends 10/01/2015 16:00:00
2) Start 10/01/2015 14:00:00 Ends 11/01/2015 19:00:00
3) Start 09/01/2015 12:00:00 Ends 12/01/2015 16:00:00
4) Start 09/01/2015 12:00:00 Ends 09/01/2015 16:00:00
```

TODAY IS

```
10/01/2015
```

I need the request to return 3 events (#1-2-3) and exclude #4 as:

```
1) Is Starting today and Ends today
2) Starts today and Ends tomorrow (so it is running today as well)
3) Started yesterday and Ends after tomorrow (so it is running today as well)
4) Is not running today
```

So the question is what is the best way to do it? And maybe someone can at least give a clew how to determine the today's start timestamp and end timestamp (10/01/2015 00:00:00 and 10/01/2015 24:00:00 if I'm correct???)

Comment: So you have start and end date in one String?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff: No-no) I have two Attributes with type Date in Core Date table...

Comment: So what is the problem to fetch only the data which startdate is < today and its enddate is > today? Or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. If you want 1,2,3 AND 4, at the same time, you just have to use a `NSPredicate` with your fetch, use `NSDateComponents` fo get yesterday and tomorrow as `NSDate` (with maybe using "midnight", and use a predicate like this: `(startDate >= %@) AND (endDate <= %@), yesterdayDate, tomorrowDate`;

Comment: What's exactly your problem? How to get `NSDate`s representing the day boundaries? How to build the `NSPredicate` string?

Comment: @Larme  I want to get #1-2-3 but NOT #4... If i will use (startDate >= %@) AND (endDate <= %@), TODAYmorning, TODAYnight as you suggested I will get only #1...

Comment: I wrote "YesterdayMorning" and "tomorrowNight", not "todays one"...

Comment: @DanielRinser The main question is to build the NSPredicate string... Something like: if period between startDate and endDate falls in period between TodayMorning and TodayNight, then show, else Dont show

Comment: @Larme Event can be 1-2 weeks long, so it will not be shown...? But this Today is inside this two weeks period...

Comment: If your issue is about logic, draw a line, put your todaymorning/todaymidnigth, : ----[--------]-----, and think about how to do it. It's like Does 3 is in [2;4] in maths.

Comment: @Larme Yes, seems like it "It's like Does 3 is in [2;4] in maths", but can you suggest any algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [core data get data from current week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758813/core-data-get-data-from-current-week)

Comment: @DavidBerry possible inappropriate comment...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think your main problem is how to get the day boundaries (that is a `NSDate` instance representing 0:00h of a specific date). This is actually quite easy:

```
NSDate *startOfDay;
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                startDate:&startOfDay
                                 interval:NULL
                                  forDate:yourDate];
```

Given any date (`yourDate`), `startOfDay` will be the same date, but at 0:00h.

With this information it should be quite straight-forward to build your predicate string. The condition should be something like this:

```
event.startDate <= endOfDay AND event.endDate >= startOfDay
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, actually I managed to get the DateStart and DateEnd timestamps (but your way is much better and will use it), but the main question is to build the predict request...cant figure out how to do it and it seems like it must be a complicated one...

Comment: Seems like something like: if (eventStart >= dayStart and eventStart <= dayEnd) OR (eventEnd>= dayStart) OR (eventStart<=dayStart and eventEnd>=dayEnd) OR (eventStart >=dayStart)

Comment: Shouldn't a simple `event.startDate <= endOfDay AND event.endDate >= startOfDay` work? Or am I missing something?

Comment: For example if event started yesterday and will end tommorow will not be shown in this case...but it must as the event is active today...Am I right?

Comment: Sure, your example would be included in the predicate.. Its start date is yesterday (which is before today 23:59) and its end date is tomorrow (which is after today 0:00).

Comment: f@ck...seems you are 100% right but need to test it a little...And I must just stop working for today))))) Please add this to your answer, I will mark it as correct one... THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Beer is on me when you will be in Berlin!)